# Lower bounds of a linear function defined on the nonnegative orthant

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it mean that a linear function $y=Ax$ with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $x\succeq 0$ is unbounded below unless $A \succeq 0$? Can we show it analytically?

Comment: What sort of objects are $y$, $A$ and $x$?

Comment: I assume by a linear function $f(x)$ with range $\mathbb R^n$ being unbounded below you mean that there is no $z\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $f(x)\succeq z$ for all $x$?

Comment: @joriki thanks for the interest. Yes this is my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \not\!\,\succeq 0$, there is some $A_{ij}\lt0$. For $x_k=\lambda\delta_{jk}$ we have $(Ax)_i=\sum_kA_{ik}x_k=\sum_kA_{ik}\lambda\delta_{jk}=\lambda A_{ij}$, and this is unbounded from below as $\lambda\to\infty$, so there is no $z\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $f(x)\succeq z$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why you define $x_k$ in this way?

Comment: @darkmoor: Because I need it that way to get the result :-) Perhaps write down the matrix and the vector in concrete form to see that a vector $x$ with only that one entry gets multiplied with the negative entry in $A$ to produce a corresponding negative entry in $y$.